# Should Tron have its franchise tag as well?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

I've been adding some missing "franchise tags" lately, and I've stumbled upon the *Tron*  related tags, namely [tron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron), [tron-legacy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron-legacy) and [tron-uprising](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron-uprising). The tag wiki for [tron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron) currently reads:

> A 1982 science fiction film about a computer programmer, Kevin Flynn, who is transported into a virtual world. In this virtual world, called the Grid, Flynn meets computer programs such as the eponymous Tron. The film spawned a franchise consisting of two films, an animated TV series, and multiple games.

Hence, the [tron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron) tag currently covers both the original movie and the whole franchise, which seems a bit off, given the way we usually use franchise tags.

Does the *Tron* universe warrant its own franchise tag?

Answer (score 12):

## Yes

There are currently:

- [16 questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron+-tron-legacy+-tron-uprising) tagged [tron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron) but not [tron-legacy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron-legacy)  or [tron-uprising](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron-uprising), so I assume these 16 questions are only about the 1982 original;
- [27 questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron-legacy+-tron) tagged [tron-legacy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron-legacy) but not [tron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron), which I assume are only about the 2011 one and for which it wouldn't make sense to tag them with the original *Tron* tag;
- [19 questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron-legacy+tron) tagged both [tron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron) and [tron-legacy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron-legacy). I haven't reviewed them all but either there was an earlier attempt at using [tron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron) as a franchise tag, or these questions cover both.
- [tron-uprising](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron-uprising) is 2 questions, not a big deal.

Keeping the [tron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron) for *all* these seems too much. I propose:

- renaming the current [tron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron) into [tron-franchise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron-franchise), [tron-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron-series) or similar. Everything gets tagged [tron-franchise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron-franchise), the way we usually use franchise tags;
- creating a [tron-1982](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron-1982) for the original movie, the way we have [alien-1979](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alien-1979) for instance.

This way, not everything is mixed up, and in case the powers that be ever dig *Tron: Ascension*'s script out of whatever hole they buried it in, we'll already have the franchise tag that goes with it.

Comment: Given that "Tron" is a character in the universe, isn't the whole deal now that there should either be a movie tag or a franchise tag, possibly separate from the character tag?

Comment: @phantom42 I think we don't need a character tag, upon reading [Tron] one probably thinks of the universe first?

Comment: what of "harry-potter" @phantom42?

Comment: To clarify here do you mean get rid of [[tag:tron]] completely and replace it with [[tag:tron-1982]] and [[tag:tron-franchise]]? If that is the case surely having [[tag:tron]] and [[tag:tron-1982]] would be a better approach.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot  I like the [thing-franchise] + [originalMovieName-date] like it's done with *Alien* for instance. The problem with [tron] is that it wouldn't sound "franchisey" enough, to me at least.

Comment: @Jenayah The general use I’ve seen is to shy away from -franchise suffixes or if using them use the movie name as the movie name without the year suffix. It seems to me like the proposal is mixing both styles.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot that's what I think is the less ambiguous, but to each his own. Tell that to [alien-franchise], [predator-series], [the-terminator-series], [riddick-franchise], [highlander-franchise] and friends :)